# Uncaught TypeError: navItem.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

While creating menu in JS and using .forEach console shows: Uncaught TypeError: navItem.forEach is not a function

I'm rather beginner in JS with error like this solving, can anyone help or show how to fix this code?
Thanks!

```js
const navItem = document.querySelector(".nav_item");

function activeLink() {
    navItem.forEach((item) =>
    item.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
}

navItem.forEach((item) =>
item.addEventListener('click',activeLink));
```

Comment: `querySelector` returns the first element in the DOM with the passed string, you're looking for `querySelectorAll`

Comment: `querySelector` will return one element, I'm not sure if you want to query a list but `id` should be unique

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is that you are using **querySelector** that returns only the first element. Instead you should use **querySelectorAll**

```
const navItem = document.querySelectorAll(".nav_item");

function activeLink() {
    navItem.forEach((item) =>
    item.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
}

navItem.forEach((item) =>
item.addEventListener('click',activeLink));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "querySelectorAll", otherwise the forEach loop won't work I think!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).